# tmux + micro text editor: shift-arrow echo keycode

Tags: tmux

Ubuntu 20.04.3, tmux 3.0a, micro text editor v2.0.10

### Description of issue

When using the [micro text editor](https://github.com/zyedidia/micro) within a `tmux` window, typing modifier key + arrows just echo the text of the key code instead of performing the the navigation or selection actions.

### Debug info

my `~/.tmux.conf` doesn't have any key bindings associated to Shift-arrows, Ctrl-arrows, Alt-arrows, Ctrl-Shift-arrows.

Here is literally the content of the `micro` editor when typing xxx-arrows

```
Shift Left/Right: [1;2D] [1;2C]
Shift Up/Down   : [1;2A] [1;2B]
Ctrl  Left/Right: [1;5D] [1;5C]
Ctrl  Up/Down   : [1;5A] [1;5B]
C-Sht Left/Right: [1;6D] [1;6C]
C-Sht Up/Down   : [1;6A] [1;6B]
Alt Left/Right  : [1;3D] [1;3C]
Alt Up/Down     : [1;3A] [1;3D]
```

Running `micro` outside of `tmux`, for example in Gnome terminal. There is no problem. ie  the modifier key + arrows performs their intended actions.

Running `nano` or `vim` within tmux, the modifier key + arrows does NOT echo the keycode `[1;xx]` in the editor area.

Also tried to enable the following option in `~/.tmux.conf` (and reload the config)

- `set-window-option -g xterm-keys on`
- `set-option -g xterm-keys on`

There is no improvement whether one or both of the options is enable. Currently my `~/.tmux.conf` doesn't set any of those options.

### QUESTION

Is this issue related to `tmux` or the `micro` text editor? And hopefully there is a fix.

Comment: Could be a `TERM` issue. What's the output of `echo "$TERM"` both inside and outside `tmux`?

Comment: @chepner within tmux `$TERM=screen-256color`, outside tmux `$TERM=xterm-256color`. In `~/.tmux.conf` I have `set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"`

Comment: Setting `set -g default-terminal "xterm-256color"` in my .tmux.conf fixed the issue for me. Running tmux in a ssh session from Windows Terminal

Comment: I'm encountering this on macOS, too, so it is not specific to Linux.

Answer (score 3):

Workaround (by `micro` author): https://github.com/zyedidia/micro/issues/983#issuecomment-355867571

Edit `~/.config/micro/bindings.json`, add

```json
{
    "\u001b[1;2A": "SelectUp",
    "\u001b[1;2B": "SelectDown",
    "\u001b[1;2C": "SelectRight",
    "\u001b[1;2D": "SelectLeft",
    "\u001b[1;3D": "WordLeft",
    "\u001b[1;3C": "WordRight",
    "\u001b[1;3A": "MoveLinesUp",
    "\u001b[1;3B": "MoveLinesDown",
    "\u001b[1;4C": "SelectWordRight",
    "\u001b[1;4D": "SelectWordLeft",
    "\u001b[1;5D": "StartOfLine",
    "\u001b[1;5C": "EndOfLine",
    "\u001b[1;6D": "SelectToStartOfLine",
    "\u001b[1;6C": "SelectToEndOfLine",
    "\u001b[1;5A": "CursorStart",
    "\u001b[1;5B": "CursorEnd",
    "\u001b[1;6A": "SelectToStart",
    "\u001b[1;6B": "SelectToEnd"
}
```